# Framer motion exit animation doesn't work with HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, framer-motion

this exact question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905140/hashrouter-react-breaking-animatepresenceframer-motion-exit-animations)

But it seems no one answered. So I will tell my problem as well;

I was handling Routing with BrowserRouter but it doesn't work while refreshing, so I went with a simple solution and switched it with HashRouter.

And framer-motion exit animations just got disabled, appearing animations and other still work fine. Only exit animations stopped.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

There is not much code to add for further informations to be honest because the problem is just this. But still I'm adding App.js too;

```
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import "./Sass/main.scss";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./Components/About";
import Trainings from "./Components/Trainings";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
const appVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      duration: 1,
    },
  },
};
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={appVariants}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
      className="App"
    >
      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <Switch location={location} key={location.key}>
          <Route path="/" exact={true}>
            <Header />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/hakkimda" exact={true}>
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/egitimler" exact={true}>
            <Trainings />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

HashRouter doesn't have location.
This is what it is written in the docs of react-router dom

> IMPORTANT NOTE: Hash history does not support location.key or
> location.state. In previous versions we attempted to shim the behavior
> but there were edge-cases we couldn’t solve. Any code or plugin that
> needs this behavior won’t work. As this technique is only intended to
> support legacy browsers, we encourage you to configure your server to
> work with  instead.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter